# form1.cs[design] disappeared in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#

I have a perfectly working c# project "project1.sln" in Visual Studio 2017. 
In an attempt to make a backup copy of the "project1", I copied the whole "project1" directory to "project2" and made few changes in .sln file, etc.

Now when I open and run the newly copied "project2.sln" from the Visual Studio 2017, it runs just fine with the Form1 that I designed. The problem is I can not find Form1.cs[Design] anywhere to edit. Where can I find the Form1.cs[Design]?

Comment: Info not needed

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake to glance the existing answer to my problem.
All I had to do was double click the Form1.cs and wait. Since my form have lots of control buttons, etc, and it just take time for it to load.

Since I answered for my own silly question, I thought I would contribute small solution on how to copy a project in Micro Soft Studio 2017.
1. Create a new directory under the same directory of the existing project.
2. Change the name of the directory, say "NewProject", and copy all the contents of the original directory
3. Open the NewProject.sln under the NewProject directory in Notepad
4. Change the first 2 occurrences of old project name to NewProject. Do NOT touch the 3 one. Leave it as is the old project name. 
5. Change once more the subdirectory name to "NewProject".